# i cant get information in my folder correctly

Tags: c

i created a coordinate system in c with graphic.h library but i can't mark points in this system. i take these points from a txt folder but these points sseem in my code 0,0 always. i thought this problem's reason is i cant read these points in txt folder. can you help me?

```
    for ( int i=0;i<number_of_points;i++){
        printf("%d. point x=%0.f   y=%0.f\n",i+1,coordinates[i].x,coordinates[i].y);
    }
```

when i tried wirte my points like above i get always 0,0. but in my txt folder there are points

i expect i can write points in my folder

Comment: Welcome, it is expected that you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. And post the inputs, the expected output and the actual output. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)